# Prove that $b_n={2n-3 \choose n-3}$ for all positive integers n greater or equal to 3

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $b_n$ be the number of n-permutations containing exactly one copy of the pattern $132.$
>   $$ \;b_n={2n-3 \choose n-3}\quad\forall n \geq 3$$

How do I prove this? Can someone give me a headstart, I have no idea how to start proving this.  Thanks!

Comment: @CalvinLin, wish I could read that, deleting the earlier comments

Comment: I would think that $b_n = (n-2)!$. You can treat $132$ as a single block, and then permute the remaining $n-2$ blocks in any order.

Comment: @TripleMajor I made some latex edits to your question. Can you see if this is what you want?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, thanks!

Comment: Are you referring to patterns in permutations, as described here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true.  For $n=4$ there are two, $1324, 4132$.  But $b_4={5 \choose 1}=5$

Comment: What about the permutations $\bf{143}$2, $\bf{243}$1, and 1$\bf{243}$?

Comment: @user84413:  I thought OP wanted to have $132$ in a block.  None of those do.  My solution agrees with Calvin Lin's

Comment: You and Calvin may be right about what the OP wanted, but I believe there are 5 permutations for n=4 with one copy of the pattern 132:  1324, 4132, 2413, 2431, 3142. (If the OP had said sequence instead of pattern, then there would only be 2, as you say.)